# Does touching semen make you junub?

Tags: taharah, ghusl

If someone became junub, then he made ghusl without washing his trousers, but then he washes the trousers after the ghusl. Does touching the maniy (semen) in this case make you junub, thus requiring to make another ghusl?

Answer (score 4):

First of all janabah is the state after emission of semen be it via intercourse (be it legal or illegal), masturbation or a wet dream.
And for leaving this state and being able to pray and worship Allah we are required to perform ghusl:

> ... And if you are in a state of janabah, then purify yourselves. But if you are ill or on a journey or one of you comes from the place of relieving himself or you have contacted women and do not find water, then seek clean earth and wipe over your faces and hands with it. Allah does not intend to make difficulty for you, but He intends to purify you and complete His favor upon you that you may be grateful. ([5:6](http://legacy.quran.com/5/6))

However scholars differed about the reason for this ghusl some say it is the state itself (and only or more exactly the act of emission of semen) others considered semen as a najasah (too) that must be cleaned during the ghusl after janabah.

As for the semen itself scholars differed about it being najis or tahir due to the fact that there are ahadith saying once that it was washed out of the clothes and another time says that it was scratched out once dry.

But there's no backup for a necessity of any "purity" ritual after touching it if a person was in a tahir state (by ghusl for example). As for the case that it is regarded as impure (najis) the fact that it is washed out with water which is a "clean and cleaning" tool in fiqh there's no necessity to do taharah on oneself. And for the case that it is regarded as pure (tahir) there's no issue here at all.

Answer (score 2):

> Does touching the maniy (semen) in this case make you junub?

The answer is: **No**

**Evidence of this is what ‘Aisha (rad) said in Hadith Sahih:**

> Allah’s Messenger (ﷺ) used to wash the semen and then go out for
>   prayer in that (very) garment and I could still see the trace of the
>   washing on it. [Agreed upon]
>
> (Narrated by "Bukhari" (229) and "Muslim" (289)) [[1]](https://sunnah.com/bulugh/1/31)

In Arabic

> عَنْ عَائِشَةَ رَضِيَ اَللَّهُ عَنْهَا, قَالَتْ: { كَانَ رَسُولُ اَللَّهِ ‏- صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏-يَغْسِلُ اَلْمَنِيَّ,
>
> ثُمَّ يَخْرُجُ إِلَى اَلصَّلَاةِ فِي ذَلِكَ اَلثَّوْبِ, وَأَنَا أَنْظُرُ إِلَى أَثَرِ اَلْغُسْلِ فِيهِ } مُتَّفَقٌ عَلَيْه ِ

**Summary**

Based on the content in Hadith the semen is pure (Taher) and doesn't require ghusl if you touched him by your hand when you washing your trousers

**Note:** The ghusl is required when semen is exit lustily (Shahwa)

I hope my answer is clear.

And Allah knows best!

**References**

1. [[1]](https://sunnah.com/bulugh/1/31) Bulugh al-Maram 27 (Chapter: The Cleansing of Najasah and its nature)
2. For more information Please, Take a look at [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/135) , [this hadith](https://sunnah.com/urn/1255350) and [These Hadiths](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=to%20wash%20the%20semen)