# Maniy still sticking on skin after Ghusl, does my Ghusl invalidated?

Tags: taharah, ghusl

Assalamualaikum,

So after I did Ghusl and I get dressed I noticed there is still maniy sticking on my skin. Does this mean it invalidates my Ghusl?

Thank you in advance, Jazakallah Khairan.

Comment: This sounds a bit strange, how fast are you performing ghusl? Don't you wash/clean your private parts while performing it? [This](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56765/does-touching-semen-make-you-junub) might be helpful.

Comment: You have to do ghusl again

Comment: @SadiqurRahman why? A statement as yours requires an explanation.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I wash my private parts and everything and I don't do it that fast either. It's just sometimes the maniy is so sticky it sticks on my leg without me noticing it.

Comment: For ghusl you must clean impurities(urine, sperm etc). If any of the major impurities remains on your body you have do ghusl again properly.

Comment: I assume that you have washed yourself to the best of your knowledge. And found the maniy later or while you are still in the bath room ... @SadiqurRahman well scholars have two different opinions on why ghusl is necessray for janabah some say it is the state itself others do so because they consider maniy najis (this opiniuon is held by the majority of scholars however most of them don't consider it as the reason for the necessity to perform ghusl). Even if maniy is najis the requirement for ghusl in the given case requires an explanation as one could simply wash it away.

Comment: @Medi1Saif I found it later when I'm already out of the bathroom.

Answer (score -1):

Maniy is not Najas. No need of bathing again. Just wash out the remaining. Bathing is for the state of Janabah. So once it is completed the state of Janabah will be moved.

Comment: Thank you for the answer brother! Can you also please state the hadeeth as well to explain it further? Thank you once again!